# Может ли этот код защитить от XSS атаки?

Tags: php, csrf, xss

На habr прочитал про необходимость использования hash для пользователей.

> Используйте хеши для пользователей. Это поможет предотвратить вызов той или иной функции путём XSS.
>
> `$secret_key = md5( strtolower( "http://site.ru/" . $member['name'] . sha1($password) . date( "Ymd" ) ) ); // $secret_key - это наш хеш`
>
> Далее во все важные формы подставляйте инпут со значением текущего хеша пользователя:
>
> `<input type="hidden" name="secret_key" value="$secret_key" />`
>
> Во время выполнения скрипта осуществляйте проверку:
>
> `if ($_POST['secret_key'] !== $secret_key)
>   {
>   exit ('Error: secret_key!');
>   }`

Вопрос: Как злоумышленник может вызвать функцию путём XSS?

Понятие про XSS и его разновидности имею.

Источник: https://habr.com/ru/post/143035/

Comment: Пост вредный, в нём понаписаны глупости, рейтинг и комментарии должны были намекнуть вам на это.

Comment: А в процитированном фрагменте автор, видимо, пытался изобрести защиту от CSRF-атак, но сделал это крайне глупо и нелепо.

Answer (score -3):

Вызвать функцию путём XSS невозможно.

> Пост вредный, в нём понаписаны глупости.
>
> А в процитированном фрагменте автор, видимо, пытался изобрести защиту от CSRF-атак, но сделал это крайне глупо и нелепо.

Comment: Копировать мысли из комментариев и выдавать за свои - это надо додуматься.

Comment: @u_mulder ну тут всё-таки цитата стоит. (Впрочем, это не отменяет того, что данные мысли не очень тянут на ответ)